# AppCompatActivity set logo in toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

My Activity extends AppCompatActivity and I can't set the logo the ActionBar.
Normally, i do so in the Manifest using "logo" attribute. Doesn't work.
in Java in the Activities with getSupportActionBar.setLogo() or setIcon(). Doesn't work.

Could someone help me?

Thx

Answer (score 7):

Try the following:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

For more info:
https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

along with

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```